# CheckedListBox and Check Listener

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkedlistbox

How can I listen when any item of a `System.Windows.Forms.CheckedListBox` has the selection changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscribe to event `ItemCheck`

Comment: No. In ItemCheck, the checked state of the items is not the latest. See the remarks in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck.aspx
Any other way?